# How to check nginx root folder

Tags: nginx, debian

I have a very basic 404 error:

> Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Details: Requested URL: /index.html

I cannot figure out which full url is finally called.

My index.html is very basic :

```
<html><body>hello</body></html>
```

My config file :

```
server {

 listen 8045;

        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/asproot;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/asp.access.log;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/asp.error.log;

location / {

        index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;

        fastcgi_index Default.aspx;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

     }

 }
```

The nginx user can access the root folder and read index.html (I tested this with `su`).
In the browser I load: `http://serverip:8045/index.html`

So what is going wrong?
How can I see what the final url is called?

---

**EDIT**

I figured out that problem comes from fastcgi. I've read several articles but i'm lost !

To avoid a long question with huge historic, i abort this and i'll post a new question once i'll have understood the basics of fastcgi with nginx. Anyway i give a config that finally works (see few answers below)

Comment: If you want I can help you - I'm hosting .NET apps on Linux, it's a common topic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i finnaly made it working.
I still have an other problem, index doesn't works
So i have to type the full address :

> http://localhost:8045/Default.aspx

if i just type :

> http://localhost:8045
>   or
>   http://localhost:8045/default.aspx

then i have a 404 error (so url is case sensitive)

As i said now fastcgi works, things still obscure and i have to improve it.
Anyway, i give you all my config , i hope this will help someone:

OS : rapbian 3.18.11 (debian)
Mono : 4.0.2
fastcgi-server4
nginx 1.2.1

**FastCGI**

config file :

```
   <apps>
<web-application>
        <name>ptitest</name>
        <vhost>*</vhost>
        <vport>8045</vport>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/usr/share/nginx/asproot</path>
</web-application>
</apps>
```

commandline :

```
CONFIG_PATH=/usr/share/nginx/fastcgimono
LOG=/var/log/fastcgi-mono4.log

MONOSERVER=$(which fastcgi-mono-server4)

${MONOSERVER} /appconfigdir=${CONFIG_PATH} /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /logfile=${LOG} --verbose &
```

**NGINX:**

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO "";

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

site-avalaible/default (i made so many tries, here what it is now) :

```
server {

 listen 8045;

        server_name ptitest;
        root /usr/share/nginx/asproot;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/asp.access.log;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/asp.error.log;

location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        }

location / {
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
     }

 }
```

**Web Content :**
/usr/share/nginx/asproot/web.config :

```
<configuration>

 <system.web>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>

 </system.web>

</configuration>
```

/usr/share/nginx/asproot/Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <% var test = String.Format("Hello World! Got an aspx page running on nginx!!!\r\n{0}",System.DateTime.Now); %>

    <%= test %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Logs**

Comment: Seems to be mostly fine as far as I can see, only a recomendation - don't use fastcgi-mono-server4. I recommend using Hyperfastcgi (https://github.com/xplicit/HyperFastCgi) - it's a rewrite to make it more performant - the mono one is damn slow. It uses a very similar config, so shouldn't be a problem migrating to it.

Comment: And in your command line for mono-fastcgi specify `MONO_IOMAP=all` - that should fix the case issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when you access the root directory, "index" directive gets applied, but when you are accessing directly, it applies the "fastcgi_pass" directive. You should probably check before the pass directive if the file is even present.

Seems like I have a similar need as yours, I use this config for it:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

    # PublicRoot
    root /usr/share/nginx/asproot;

    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/asp.access.log main buffer=50k;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/asp.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @fastcgi;
    }

    # Fastcgi-pass
    location @fastcgi {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }


}
```

Here I first go by "try_files" directive to check if I can get the static file, but if not, I go then by the fastcgi_pass directive. But I'm hosting the aspx files in different folder, not the same with static files.

Comment: you are right, i figured out that 404 happens when i write fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 line. In a other hand fastcgi seems listening as espected (tested with (sudo netstat -lap | grep 9000) .So now we have to find a way to test fastcgi config...

Comment: Well, THAT is a totally different config, sure. Without seeing it we can't say way much.